# Override function SonataAdmin symfony2 v2.3

Tags: php, symfony

When running the application gives the following error:

> Declaration of
>   AppBundle\Controller\TematicasAdminController::editAction() should be
>   compatible with
>   Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::editAction($id = NULL,
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request = NULL)

### My Controller

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class TematicasAdminController extends Controller
{
    public function editAction($id = null)
    {
        $result = parent::editAction($id);

        return $result;
    }

}
```

---

Symfony version 2.3
Sonata admin version 2.4@dev

Does anyone could help me?
Thanks
Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent class method (`CRUDController::editAction`) has second parameter:

```
CRUDController::editAction($id = NULL, Request $request = NULL)
```

Please add `$request = null` as second argument to your `TematicasAdminController::editAction` as you already did with `$id` argument.

Comment: Please clear the cache or double check. This error means only one - just what I described - arguments in Your method must match the parent's ones.